# Zeros of a complex function on the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, roots, closed-form, roots-of-unity

I need a closed form for the zeros of $$f(z):=\frac{z^{2(1+\omega)}-z^{2\omega}}{i}-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}} $$ where $z$ lies on the unit circle $|z|=1$ and $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

We know that the cube roots of unity satisfy $$1+\omega+\omega^2=0\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \omega^3=1$$
Now we have
$$\frac{z^{2(1+\omega)}-z^{2\omega}}{i}-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}=0$$
So $$e^{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}z^{2\omega}\left(\frac{z^2-1}{i}\right)-1=0$$
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $1+\omega = - \omega^2 = -\frac{1}{\omega}$ and $i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = -e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Maybe these substitutions could be useful?

Comment: Define $z^{2\omega}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Since $z$ lies on the unit circle and $2\omega=-1+\sqrt{3} i$ so we define $$z^{2\omega}=e^{i t (-1+\sqrt{3} i)}=e^{-it-\sqrt{3} t}$$

Comment: @TonyMathew Thanks a lot for the idea. I tried but cannot come to an answer. I request you for help.

Comment: You can rearrange into $z^{2\omega+2}-z^{2\omega}=ie^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt 3}}$ and substitute $u=z^{2\omega}$ to get $u^{1+1\frac1\omega}-u= ie^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt 3}}$. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) for series solution for general trinomial.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you for the wonderful idea. I would really appreciate if you write an answer and give a closed form for zeros. I will with utmost respect accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerically, $z=\sqrt[6]{-1}$ is the only $|z|=1$ solution to $$z^{1+ i\sqrt 3}-z^{-1+ i\sqrt 3}=ie^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt 3}}$$

Now [substituting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Other_characterizations#:%7E:text=Let&text=,the%20general%20form) $z=\pm\sqrt w$ and use [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) for the other equation:

$$\begin{align}z^{1- i\sqrt 3}-z^{-1- i\sqrt 3}=ie^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt 3}}\iff z^2=i e^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}}z^{2\sqrt[3]{-1}}+1\iff w= (\pm 1)^{2\sqrt[3]{-1}}i e^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}}w^\sqrt[3]{-1}+1\implies z=\pm 1\pm\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(i(\pm 1)^{2\sqrt[3]{-1}}e^{-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}}\right)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}w^{\sqrt[3]{-1}n-\frac12}\right|_1\end{align}$$

to finally use the [Fox Wright function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function#:%7E:text=special%20case%20of%20the%20Fox%20H%2Dfunction), a special case of [Fox H](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html):

$$\bbox[5pt,border: 1px solid blue]{\begin{align}z=\pm1\pm\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\pm i e^{-\frac{\{1,7\}\pi}{2\sqrt 3}}\right)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\sqrt[3]{-1}n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac32+(-1)^\frac23n\right)}=\pm1\pm\frac12\,_1\Psi_1\left(^{\left(\frac12,\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)}_{\left(\frac32,(-1)^\frac23\right)};\pm i e^{-\frac{\{1,7\}\pi}{2\sqrt 3}} \right)\end{align}}$$

where one solution takes $+,1$ and the other takes $-,7$. [Both](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2B1%2F2+sum%5B%28%2B1+i+e%5E%28-%28+%CF%80%29%2F%282+sqrt%283%29%29%29%29%5En%2Fn%21+%CE%93%281%2F2+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2F%CE%93%283%2F2+-+n+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C1500%7D%5D) [roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B0-1-1%2F2+sum%5B%28-1+i+e%5E%28-%28+7+%CF%80%29%2F%282+sqrt%283%29%29%29%29%5En%2Fn%21+%CE%93%281%2F2+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2F%CE%93%283%2F2+-+n+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C10%5D) [match Wolfram Alpha’s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5E%281-i+%E2%88%9A3%29+-z%5E%28-1-+i%E2%88%9A3%29%3Di+exp%28-%CF%80%2F%282+%E2%88%9A3%29%29). [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B-1%2F2+sum%5B%28-1+i+e%5E%28-%28+7+%CF%80%29%2F%282+sqrt%283%29%29%29%29%5En%2Fn%21+%CE%93%281%2F2+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2F%CE%93%283%2F2+-+n+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C10%5D) calculates $z+1$ more precisely for $z$ being the root taking $-,7$ as it’s real part is almost $-1$.

Comment: $+1$ and Thank you for the wonderful answer. I would request a closed form of the zeros.

Comment: The Fox Wright function is not classically defined as having complex parameters, but if you consider an extension, then it could work

Answer (score 1):

$$\omega^3=1\implies\omega\in\{1,-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3},-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3}\}$$

$$|z|=1$$
$\ $

$$\frac{z^{2(1+\omega)}-z^{2\omega}}{i}-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}=0\tag{1}$$

We see, equation (1) is an algebraic equation over $\mathbb{C}$ of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($z^{2(1+\omega)},z^{2\omega}$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $z$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation. We have to guess $z$ therefore.

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

**1) Solutions in terms of Elementary functions**

**1a) $\omega=1$**

$$\frac{z^4-z^2}{i}-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}=0$$

We see, this equation is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic equation of $z$.

$$z\in\left\{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{1+4e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}i}},-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{1+4e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}i}},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1+4e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}i}},-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1+4e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}i}}\right\}$$

There is no $z$ with $|z|=1$.

**1b) $z=\sqrt[6]{-1}$**

Tyma Gaidash wrote in his answer, numerically, $z=\sqrt[6]{-1}$ is a solution.

$$z=\sqrt[6]{-1}\implies z\in\left\{-i,i,-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+2i\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+2i\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2i\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-2i\sqrt{3}}\right\}$$

Numerically, we find that
$$z=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+2i\sqrt{3}}$$
is a solution of the equation for
$$\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3}$$
with $|z|=1$.

**2) Solutions in terms of nonelementary functions**

$$\frac{z^{2(1+\omega)}-z^{2\omega}}{i}-e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}=0\tag{1}$$

We see, equation (1) is a trinomial equation with complex exponents.

$$z^{2(1+\omega)}-z^{2\omega}-ie^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}=0$$
$$-\frac{1}{i}e^{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}z^{2\omega}+\frac{1}{i}e^{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}z^{2(1+\omega)}-1=0$$
$z\to e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}\omega}}(-xi)^\frac{1}{2\omega}$:
$$x-e^{\frac{\pi}{\omega}i}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}\omega}}i^\frac{1}{\omega}x^{\frac{1}{\omega}+1}-1=0$$

Now the equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)